# Without publishing the app on appstore, how to push updates for my iOS application?

Tags: ios, app-store

After publishing the app on appstore, is there a way to push the changes in the view/layout, also the underlying functionality of the settings screen(or any other screen) without having user to update the app from app store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No , there is no way to accomplish this you have to create and upload a new build for every view/layout update , your issue is possible if you previously embed that logic inside the uploaded version and dynamically do this according to server responses which is not a recommended way

Comment: Remote configuration and A/B testing are actually a way with which the bigger players test future updates on a restricted range of users before distributing them to the larger public.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: There are many, many apps that download changing data and display it in a tableview or collection view. Different text, images, etc. That is, in effect, *changing the app* without submitting an update.

Depending on what exactly you want to do, it may be fairly straight-forward or it may be complex.

For example, you may have a section of code that lays out an "options" screen, and you decide to add a new option. Your app could connect to a server, download a "configuration" file, and then have your code re-layout the screen as needed.

So, sure, it's possible - you just need to plan ahead and code your app for that flexibility.

One note, however: if you're thinking of *significant* changes to your app's design and/or functionality, you may run into issues with Apple's guidelines. For example, don't use that idea to try and "get around" having your app rejected for inappropriate content (such as having a "hidden" gambling section that would only be revealed after the app has been published).